# HTML Formatting a Data-Container of a SPAN in a Bootstrap Popover

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, string-formatting

I am using a SPAN as a popover
:

```
<div class="col-xs-2 pull-right">
    <span class="icon-help tooltip-help pull-right" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-content="<b>This</b> is Photoshop's version of Lorem Ipsum..." data-trigger="hover">
    </span>
</div>
```

I would like to format the data-content string using HTML. It doesn't appear to allow formatting. Is there a data-container setting that will enable me to format the data-content with HTML?

Comment: Why wouldn't you put the actual content inside the `<span>` instead of trying to describe it in a data attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed you are using Bootstrap (`pull-left` and `data-toggle="popover"` etc).

Looking at [popovers](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers) there is a `html` config option for rendering HTML instead of text.

```
Name    Type    Default Description
html    boolean false   Insert HTML into the popover. If false, jQuery's text method will be used to insert content into the DOM. Use text if you're worried about XSS attacks.
```

Use `data-html="true"` and try:

```
<span data-toggle="popover" data-container="body" data-placement="bottom" data-html="true" data-content="<b>This</b> Lorem Ipsum..." data-trigger="hover">
```